# How can I find all music files in android device with unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, user-permissions

At the code below is my way to get path of downloads or Music Folder.
But At the end it say's that you don't have a permission even though I have.
In the Explanation below i explain that how I get error. **But my main goal is not just solve that error my main goal is find all music files in android with unity**.
I searched too much answer in the internet but I could not solve this problem. I can play all musics that i want in windows through this way but it doesn't work on android. I can't understand that in the app info it shows that i gave the permission to all files but how it can be possible that program could not recognize that permission?

In the first scene I'm asking for permissions. After accepting that permissions it automatically redirects me to the next scene which in that scene I'm trying to get Music or downloads folder in device. But it throws an exeption.

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.your.bundle.identifier" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

This is my asking permission code

```
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonPressing : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool questionAsked;
    private void Start()
    {
        questionAsked = false;
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
        Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
        questionAsked = true;
        StartCoroutine(MyRoutine());
#endif
    }

    private IEnumerator MyRoutine()
    {
        questionAsked = true;
        if (questionAsked && Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead) &&Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
        {   questionAsked = false;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }
        else if (questionAsked && Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
        {
            questionAsked = false;
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead);

        }


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

        StartCoroutine(MyRoutine());
    }
}
```

And here I'm trying to get downloads or music folder.

```
 [Obsolete("Obsolete")]
    public void GetFiles()
    {
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
        if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead)&&Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
        {
            _camera.backgroundColor = Color.grey;
            _path = "/storage";
            directoryTexts.text+= _path + "\n";
            try
            {
                string[] allDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(_path, "*Music*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                directoryTexts.text += allDirectories.Length + "\n";
                if (allDirectories.Length!=0)
                {
            
                    foreach (var allDirectory in allDirectories)
                    {
                        directoryTexts.text+= allDirectory + "\n";
                    }
            
                }
                else
                {
                    directoryTexts.text += "There is no directory \n";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                directoryTexts.text += e + "\n";
                throw;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            directoryTexts.text += "You Dont Have a permission \n";
        }
#endif
}
```

But everytime i get this Exeption
[Exeption Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Jnn.png)

By the way in the image "Yes it has" means yes it has a permission. I have checked it in start function. In Addition
I have found in this forum https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-10-and-scoped-storage-missed-features-in-unity-2019.749333/ that  others have the same issue.But no one couln'd not solve this problem.

Comment: Problem is in the else statement.  You do not have permission to read _path = "/storage";.  If you did than error message would be displayed in the CATCH.  So you must be getting error at directoryTexts.text += "Basin qacmasin \n";

Comment: I asked permission for readexternalstorage and in the app i accpeted it.                         
if(Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead)&&Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite)) this statement gives me true whcih means i must be able to read that directory.

Comment: You right.  The image show that IEnumerator is failing in System.IO.  So GetDirectories() is failing.  The error could be a subdirectory or a file.

Comment: Still could not find what is the problem. I have edited image and my question and I hope it will help to understand the others to find what is the problem.

Comment: One or  more of the files/directories(you do not have permission to read.  I will post sample code of how to recursively get the files/folders.   It should find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After long researches I found that I have to request ManageExternalStorage permission
in order to acces media files in android 11. But in android 10 my code work without any error. Here is [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) , [Documentation1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#:%7E:text=Users%20can%20see%20which%20apps,files%22%20is%20read%2Donly.) for java. And with [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) and [AndroidJavaObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html)
in Unity you can substitue java code with C# code.

Answer (score -1):

This should find issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);
            
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
             

                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than just a random code snippet could you add some more explanation how exactly this addresses and fixes OP's issue?

Comment: @derHugo : DirectoryInfo terminates when there is an access exception.  The code above does equivalent using recursion and has exception handlers so when an exception occurs an error message is output indicating the file/folder that fails and then the code continues

Comment: well from the question we already know that the path that fails is the access to `/storage` ... so the very first `Directory.GetDirectories(_path, "*Music*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` already throws ...

Comment: @derHugo : Is it a file or is it the entire directoy or one of the subdirectories?

Comment: It is the plain access to the root directory `/storage` just as the error message says: `Access to the path '/storage' is denied`

Comment: okay then let me change my question. I just want to find music files in android. Because of that i was tried to get music or download folder if you know any other solutions please let me know. @jdweng

Comment: You do not have permission to access the files/folders.

Comment: Actually i found why i don't have a permission to that files. Because of the my manifest file and ask permission code. I have to get permission to all files but in Unity i can access only read and write permission to media files. In android 10 and i 11 doesn't let you get permission to all files with my code. And In Unity i can't get permission to all files. Because of that i exported my project to change my manifest and asking permission code with android studio i don't know how to do that yet but I think I can find from Internet

Comment: You need to be a window admin on Android : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin

Comment: I don't think that i should be admin.In my opinion I just need to request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. I can't do that with Unity's default permission codes. But in unity there have a [AndroidJavaClass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) and [AndroidJavaObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html) With this codes i should ask ManageExternalStorage permission to get a permission to all files. Now I'm trying to do that I hope it 'll help me.

Comment: You should be able in windows to change permissions.  If you can't change permission in windows that you will not be able to in Java.  Then you will need to be an Admin to change permissions.

Comment: I tried my app in Android 10 and it worked. So for now I'm trying to request permission to manage external storage for all files. I don't really understand the AndroidJavaObject and AndroidJavaClass that much but I'm trying to learn from internet. Because it's really hard to me  to change java codes to c# codes with that Classes.

Comment: Java and c# are just languages and what you can do in one you can do in the other.  And the opposite is also true.  What you can't do in one you cannot do in the other.  So if permission are wrong the Java will fail just like in c#.  You have to fix the permissions.  Most likely the app created the music also created permissions that only the app can access.  Java will also have same issue as your c#.

Comment: I know what you want to say but that wasn't what I'm talking about. I'm saying that only in android java class you get permission for all files and Unity still don't have that permission. You can access that permission through AndroidJavaClass in unity. But for example in android studio you it's easy to do. Because in android studio that permission libraries has been added by default. If i was created my program in android studio i could be able to get that permission easily and that wouldn't be a problem. The thing is it's hard to do it in Unity. And I'm searching for help for that.